# Flutter : How to Automaticallly scroll to end of SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a SingleChildScrollView, its scrollDirection is set to Horizontal with 5 child widgets placed inside a Row Widget.
I want to programmatically scroll to the last widget in the Row and when the last widget is reached(waits 2 seconds) I want to scroll backward.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
    child:Row(
            children:<Widget>[
                           Widget(),
                           Widget(),
                           Widget(),
                           Widget(),
                           Widget(),  
                         ],
            ), 
    ),
```

)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using scroll controller in following way.

```
  ScrollController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController();
     WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _controller.animateTo(
           _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
           duration: Duration(seconds: 1), 
           curve: Curves.ease,
        )
        .then((value) async {
           await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
           _controller.animateTo(
              _controller.position.minScrollExtent,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1), 
              curve: Curves.ease,
           );
        });
     });
  }

  callMeWidget() {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _controller,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              callMeWidget(),
              callMeWidget(),
              callMeWidget(),
              callMeWidget(),
              callMeWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This does solve one part. But after the list reaches its end I want to scroll backward. This should happen after a delay of 2 seconds.

Answer (score 12):

I have a better and more efficient method :

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      reverse: true,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          ***
        ],
      ),
    );
```

as simple as that :)

It will scroll to the end as soon as a new widget is added !

Comment: This works, but when we manually scroll back to the top and then add a new widget, it does not automatically scroll to the bottom.

Comment: @sj_959 Maybe a bug. It should scroll automatically if a widget is inserted using setstate().

Comment: Excellent idea. Also the code should be ```reverse: true, child:*** ```